# Multiple clickable icons to PrimeNG TreeNode in Angular2 application

Tags: javascript, html, angular, primeng

I am developing an angular2 application using PrimeNG. I have a tree view and in certain scenarios I need to add more than one icon to specific tree node. Any help on this is appreciated.

Example:

```
  
Icon TreeNode1
     Icon1 Icon2 TreeNode2
```

I want the icons to be clickable so that I can perform actions like showing tooltips or show popup dialog etc...

Open on suggestions regarding any other technology that can be used to achieve above funtionality

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something related and found your question right now.
To add multiple icons to a branch (or leaf) of the tree you need to make your own templates for each type of TreeNode.`

```
<ng-template let-node  pTemplate="group">
        <i class="fa fa-bolt" (click)="doSomething('do lighting stuff')></i>
        <span>{{node.label}}</span>
</ng-template>
<ng-template let-node  pTemplate="node">
        <i class="fa fa-signal" (click)="doSomething('do signal stuff')></i> <i class="fa fa-info" (click)="doSomething('do info stuff')></i>
        <span>{{node.label}}</span>
</ng-template>
```

`

Check here the TreeNode interface https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/common/treenode.ts